# What is the difference between installing a software from deb file, and installing it from the software market as snap package?

Tags: software-installation, software-center, snap, software-sources

Recently, I was planning to install Opera browser on my system, so I visited the official website, and downloaded the `.deb` file, and installed it.

However, to my concern, for every update, I will be needing to download the `.deb` file again and again, since I have not updated the repository in Software & Updates section. At this point I thought, Chrome itself added the repository, so maybe Opera must have done it too, but it didn't.

Same issue with the Discord application, i.e., I have to visit the official website and download the `.deb` file for timely-updates.

However, I found that the Ubuntu software market ships both, Opera and Discord, but as snap packages. So I thought to give it a try, since it would relief me of downloading the `.deb` files from the official website, and I can update them with just a command.

Here, I was recommended by some friends of mine that I shouldn't opt for the snap, because of some errors or something, which I am currently completely unaware of, and instead go for the official `.deb` files.

Can someone explain me the differences?

EDIT: Since past few months, Chromium has too moved itself to the snap packages. Does this have any difference from past when it was in `apt-get` package system?

Comment: The Chromium snap package launches a little more slowly the old Chromium apt package. Once Chromium's open the performance is about the same. The Chromium snap package seems to me to be more stable than the old Chromium apt package. Overall I prefer the Chromium snap package.

Comment: Any comments about Discord or Opera

Comment: When you installed Opera from the .deb, it gave you the option to update it with the regular system packages (automatically adding the repo). Uninstall it, install it again, and pick the option to update it with the system.

Comment: @KGIII thnx man, but should or shouldn't I go for snap? What's your person opinion?

Comment: Downloading and executing a `.deb` file is one of the absolute worst ways to install software.  Installing packages this way that are installable by your package manager is a good way to wreck your system or end up in dependency hell.  It's somewhat opinion based, but I would prioritize software installation from best to worst method: 1) apt / GUI package manager; 2) snap/flatpak/appimage; 3) PPA; 4) .deb file; 5) manual compilation from source only when necessary

Comment: *Personally*, I disable the entire snap app system and don't use them.

Comment: If the package is available in Ubuntu repositories, use apt or the software center

Comment: @Nmath that's what my concern is. For eg. Opera and Discord ships deb and also snap, which is in Ubuntu Market

Comment: Snaps work, but they usually have less permissions on the system than a .deb.  Some permissions can be allowed when installing, like printing a page from browser to printer.  Snaps are good for developers since only one snap is needed for different versions of Ubuntu,  .debs need to be made for each version.

Comment: IMO it's better to use the snap because it won't screw up your package manager. But I suggest that you do more research on the different methods, since you'll only get opinions on the topic and only from the people who reply to this comment thread, which is such an underrepresented sample that it's not really useful (this is the reason that questions soliciting opinions are off topic on AU)

Comment: Snaps are usually front and centre in software store,  .debs can need a bit more searching if both versions supplied.